# Notepad++ "wait" when recording macros

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ plays back everything you record in a macro instantly and this is problematic for me. I have 3 macros that i have to run one after the other and I tried to make another macro that plays those 3 macros. But there is no wait time between macros, when I run the 4th macro all 3 macros action are executed at once.

Any way to fix this? Can't find any obvious solution myself.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for text manipulation to have any sense of time; it is just a sequence of instructions to be executed in a certain order.  Could you give an example of your current output vs your expected output?  Perhaps your macros were created in such a way that the later macros are behaving differently due to the changes from running the earlier macros.

Comment: For example i need to insert something at the end of each line, than i need to replace a string that contains characters from original lines and stuff i previously added.

Comment: I'm looking for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something that we can use to replicate the problem *exactly*.  That said, I think this is a quirk with the way Notepad++ handles search/replace in macros: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/968 https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/1290590/thread/86ea7a57/

Comment: Hmm it seems i can't reproduce it now. I re-recorded all 3 macros in 1 take and now it works as it should. But I had this problem in the past too, recorded some actions in Notepad++ and when i played them the results were incomplete. Recorded same actions with EmEditor and they worked as they should.

Comment: Do you think you can go with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)? You might need to write your macros manually, but it can insert any delay or perform any other action when executing a macro. For example `Send Hello↵Sleep 2000↵Send World` waits 2 seconds between typing Hello and World. [Macro recorders](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98820-is-there-any-way-to-record-a-macro-in-ahk-or-any-recorder-compatible-with/) also exist.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind, next time i have problem's i'll try it